# Exclaimer mail utilities bounce back

Tags: email

```
SPF: fail (Exclaimer Mail Utilities: domain of domain.co.uk does not designate 194.xx.x.xx as permitted sender) client-ip=194.xx.x.xx; envelope-from=user@domain.co.uk; helo=smtp1.bt.net; ########
```

This is the bounce back that is being received, what does this mean and how can I go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

we had something similar happen to us. I believe Mail Utilities checks the SPF record for your domain in DNS but this does not match the host address your email address is coming from. Because the two do not match the message has been classified as an SPF Fail and rejected. Try checking your SPF record in DNS for your domain. You might be able to find more info here http://www.openspf.org/.